# WordPress parent-child menu HTML

Tags: php, wordpress

Suppose I have this simple menu with a parent-child item:

- Home
- About us
- Parent page

  - childpage 1
  - childpage 2

WordPress just stacks these links next to eachother as if they are all equal in hierarchial order (which they aren't).

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">childpage 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">childpage 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I use `wp_nav_menu();` to retrieve this menu. Is there any way so that it intelligently outputs this menu as:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">childpage 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">childpage 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Side note: your HTML is not valid. You have to re-wrap nested element by `<ul></ul>` See [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists#Nesting_lists)

Comment: Just making sure are you using?

In WP control panel Appeareance>Menus

Comment: HTML fixed, wp_nav_menu() function works fine, the issue is the way it outputs parent->subpages

Comment: Do you need to dynamically update the menus - or can you manually change them? And as per the other questions are you using a WordPress menu within WordPress (Appearance>Menus)? If you are using WordPress menus, if you drag a page to the right below its parent it becomes a child page and gets nested in a <ul> it does not do this automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WordPress dynamic menus **are independent of the WordPress parent/child relationships for pages**. Menus themselves are an independent post type.

If you want to have your menu as output with submenus you have to create the menu in Design -> Menus and drag & drop the items to the right side to be child items.

With the custom menu functionality of WordPress you could even build menus where child pages are parents in the menu and parent pages are childs in the menu for instance.

The pages parent/child relationships are for better organization in the backend, for the permalinks and may matter in functions where you just list your pages.

Comment: That's clear and precise, thank you.

I wish the parent/child page relations were automatically applied in the menu. Is there any way to achieve this with a plugin or published code?

Comment: Unfortunatly not. The custom menu function is as its name suggests - for "custom menus". You may be looking for wp_list_pages() or a similar function. Those can list pages with respect to the parent/child relationship.

Comment: I found a fantastic plugin that automatically syncs pages and menus (even in the right order) by the name of "Nested pages".